# Issue in getting data using CURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am sending request to API using CURL, but not able to get request. The API works well when you call it directly in browser.

Here is the link

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=5d9cp7nfxruc7p788fvvqpwn&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&hotelId=123912
```

my CURL code is here

```
  $post_string1 = "cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=5d9cp7nfxruc7p788fvvqpwn&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&type=xml&hotelId=123912";  

  $path1 = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info"; //Relative path to the file with $_POST parsing

$ch1 = curl_init($path1); 
$fp1 = fopen('hotel.xml','w');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string1); //Send the data to the file
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml')); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp1);
$val = curl_exec($ch1);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);//Close curl session
fclose($fp1); //Close file overwrite

//$hotel = simplexml_load_file('hotel.xml');

echo '<pre>';print_r($info);
```

I get http 405 code. Please advice what i am doing wrong.

Comment: 403 forbidden: your credentials aren't valid. As simple as that.

Comment: Remove url from `$post_string1`, it only should contain the post params. `$post_string1 = 'cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=5d9cp7nfxruc7p788fvvqpwn&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&type=xml&hotelId=123912';`

Comment: sorry but i modified my question. Its 405 code. wrong typo :)

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed: you can't use POST when the server was expecting a GET (or vice-versa)

Comment: @M Shahzad Khan Just Copy my code and execute yourself. its working good

Comment: yes, but we want to know WHY shazad's code does not work and yours do. We're not just looking for code, but for knowledge!

Comment: @STTLCU, seems like POST method is not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this

```
$post_string1 = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=5d9cp7nfxruc7p788fvvqpwn&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&type=xml&hotelId=123912";  
$header[] = "Accept: application/json";
  $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_string1 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  print_r($response);  exit;
```

Comment: Thanks srivi. I think POST method is not allowed in this api. Can i use this code in loop to get data for multiple hotels?

Comment: if you want multi hotel result use http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=14. Please read this documentation http://developer.ean.com/. Its contain all your need with examples

Comment: By multiple i meant, keep requesting with different hotel Id's in foreach or for loop. Possible?

Comment: @M Shahzad Khan Ya sure

Comment: @NathanSrivi you shouldn't fish so hard for points. It's a bad practice to accept an answer within the first 24hrs.